# Strange `gsub' for nil:NilClass in paperclip. Code works in console, but not in server

Tags: macos, imagemagick, paperclip

I am using gem paperclip (3.5.1) in rails(3.2.13) for uploading images to S3. I need to resize them, so I have imagemagick(6.8.6-3:) and I am on OS X 10.8.

Everything worked great, I was able to upload image to S3, so I decided to add :thumb and :medium sizes to styles in has_attached_files. It is working from console on test image, but not when I try to upload the same image and save it in controller. I get this error:

> Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"G15ab7cv9a7N8YT2gMuRSV+DqzNIEDK5/M+Cno/XLbE=", "qqfile"=>"test.jpg", "locale"=>"en"}
>   User Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 LIMIT 1 
>   Command :: file -b --mime './app/assets/images/test.jpg' Command :: identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg.jpg[0]' 
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg.jpg[0]' 
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg.jpg[0]' 
>   Command :: identify -format %m '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg.jpg[0]' 
>   Command :: convert '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "100x100>" '/var/folders/df/lhvn6g596fl5vmpwym6t04c80000gn/T/test20130814-88788-1kazksg20130814-88788-6efk1m' Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1777ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `gsub' for nil:NilClass):

So it crashes on this line:

```
@document.original = uploaded_file
```

But only when I have this in *Document.rb*:

```
has_attached_file :original, :styles => {:thumb => "100x100>",:small  => "150x150>", :medium => "400x400"}
```

When I leave `:styles = {}`, everything works and it's also working from console, so I am confused. I think it might be something with permissions in OS X for imagemagick.